# How to fix 'Type error "(ModelName)" object is not iterable'?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm working on Django Admin, making an action to create several model instances from other model information.

I have two models:
- Item
- ItemCopy

I tried to do this through a for loop using:

```py
def copy_action(self, request, obj):
    items_to_copy = []
    for item in Item.objects.all():
        items_to_copy.append(
             ItemCopy(name=item.name, description=item.description)
        )
```

In others actions I have the same code with another model and it is works, but when I tried to do this throw me 'Type error 'ItemCopy' object is not iterable'

Comment: This seems like it should work, does the error message point to that function as the cause?

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulk_create after for loop:

```
YourModel.objects.bulk_create(your_list)
```

Comment: I wanna avoid bulk_create 'cause is a formset of a custom action

Answer (score 0):

I solve to accomplish this using the following syntax:

```
def copy_action(self, request, obj):
items_to_copy = []
for item in Item.objects.all():
    items_to_copy.append(
         {'name':item.name, 'description':item.description}
    )
```

and It works...